# Blender Particle System Convert to Mesh Button not visible

Tags: particles

I have added cylider as object particle to cube, then I tried to convert particle to mesh but the convert button in modifiers tab is not visible[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are instancing objects (the cylinders) the button you want to press is the "make instances real" whereas if your particles where paths then the "convert to mesh" button would reappear